# Multiple Ecommerce Functionality in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, multistore, multi-website

I am new to Magento so pardon me if I sound stupid. I want to build an Ecommerce website in magento 2 which have following functionality:

- Simple Ecommerce Functionality like products, categories and so on
- Freelancers (User can visit the website check the profile of freelancer and order it. Now obviously freelancers will have different prodcut detail page with their profile and will have different categories)

So my question is how can I have two different kind of product like simple products and freelancers and also I want to communicate the data between them like each freelancer can be linked to simple product. How can I achieve multiple ecommerce functionality like this in magento 2 and how will I override layouts for both kind of prodcuts separatly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to do the following things.

**1. Simple Product** : This is by default functionality provided by magento it self.

**2. Freelancers Product** : Create the new product type into the system by following this one.https://magecomp.com/blog/create-new-product-type-magento-2/

Now, either on simple product or on freelancers type product create one attribute and links those both things.

Comment: Hi Dhiren Vasoya,
Thanks for your answer. I am a student and learning magento 2. I have started digging into it and learnt some basic stuff like blocks, layouts, templates, modules etc. Can you give me some protips on how should I learn? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is not any specific, tips, but yes you can ask the question when you struct. And if above answer help you please upvote and accept as solutions so it will help other in community.